# Unable to "Await" Asynchronous function with Stimulsoft Reports in Node.js

Tags: node.js, stimulsoft

I Need to be able to call some JS and wait until it finishes with stimulsoft reports.

I think possibly, they may have their own "flavour" of async.

The original code looks like this

```
report.renderAsync(() => {
    console.log("Report rendered. Pages count: ", report.renderedPages.count);

    // Export to PDF
    report.exportDocumentAsync((pdfData: any) => {
        // Converting Array into buffer
        var buffer = Buffer.from(pdfData)

        // File System module
        var fs = require('fs');

        // Saving string with rendered report in PDF into a file
        fs.writeFileSync('./Invoice.pdf', buffer);
        console.log("Rendered report saved into PDF-file.");
    }, Stimulsoft.Report.StiExportFormat.Pdf);
});
```

I have tried various combinations similar to the code below, but I cannot get it to "await"  properly - everything else runs and then this code runs at the end,

```
const result = await report.renderAsync(async() => {
    console.log("Report rendered. Pages count: ", report.renderedPages.count); // << this outputs after all code! 
    // Export to PDF
    await report.exportDocumentAsync(async (pdfData: any) => {
        // Converting Array into buffer
        var buffer = Buffer.from(pdfData)

        // File System module
        //var fs = await require('fs');

        // Saving string with rendered report in PDF into a file
        //await fs.writeFileSync('./Invoice.pdf', buffer);
        console.log("Rendered report saved into PDF-file.");
        return buffer
    }, Stimulsoft.Report.StiExportFormat.Pdf);
});
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a promise and wrapping in async function.

```
report.renderAsync(async() => {
  console.log("Report rendered. Pages count: ", report.renderedPages.count);

  // Export to PDF
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    report.exportDocumentAsync((pdfData: any) => {
      // Converting Array into buffer
      var buffer = Buffer.from(pdfData)

      // File System module
      var fs = require('fs');

      // Saving string with rendered report in PDF into a file
      fs.writeFileSync('./Invoice.pdf', buffer);
      console.log("Rendered report saved into PDF-file.");
      resolve();
    }, Stimulsoft.Report.StiExportFormat.Pdf);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a standard callback, it is just named with Async.

This is the machine you are looking for:

```
const getReport = () => new Promise(resolve => 
 report.renderAsync(() => {
    console.log("Report rendered. Pages count: ", report.renderedPages.count);

    // Export to PDF
    report.exportDocumentAsync((pdfData: any) => {
        // Converting Array into buffer
        var buffer = Buffer.from(pdfData)

        // File System module
        var fs = require('fs');

        // Saving string with rendered report in PDF into a file
        fs.writeFileSync('./Invoice.pdf', buffer);
        console.log("Rendered report saved into PDF-file.");
        resolve(report.renderedPages)
    }, Stimulsoft.Report.StiExportFormat.Pdf);
});
```

Then use it like this:

```
getReport().then(pages => console.log(pages.count))
```

or:

```
async function doSomethingWithReport() {
  const renderedPages = await getReport()
  // do something with them
}

doSomethingWithReport()
```

The Google search you needed is "How do I Promisfy a callback".

Answer (score 0):

I'm be able to use with double promise

```
await new Promise(render => {
            report.renderAsync(async () => {
                console.log("Report rendered. Pages count: ", report.renderedPages.count);
                // Export to PDF
                await new Promise(resolve => {
                    report.exportDocumentAsync((pdfData: any) => {
                        // Converting Array into buffer
                        const buffer = Buffer.from(pdfData);
                        // File System module
                        const fs = require("fs");
                        // Saving string with rendered report in PDF into a file
                        fs.writeFileSync(generatedFileName, buffer);
                        console.log("Rendered report saved into PDF-file.");
                        resolve(report.renderedPages);
                    }, Stimulsoft.Report.StiExportFormat.Pdf);
                });
                render();
            });
        });
const data = readFileSync(generatedFileName);
```